# Proof for supA, hints appreciated

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to teach myself some math. I am struggeling a little bit with the following excercise: Let $A$ be a subset of  $R$ and nonempty and bounded above, and let $s \in R$ have the property that for all $n \in N$, $s+1/n$ ist an upper bounded for $A$ and $s-1/n$ ist not an upper bound for $A$. Show $s=supA$.

I am lacking some discussants. Can give someone a little hint how to start?

Thanks!

Comment: You can start with the definition of supremum of a set.

Answer (score 0):

By trichotomy, one of $s < \sup A$, $s = \sup A$, or $s > \sup A$ is true.  Since we want to show equality, we should show that neither inequality holds.

Suppose $s < \sup A$.  Sketch: Then there is some positive $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $s + x = \sup A$.  You should show that the sequence $\left(s + \frac{1}{n}\right)_{n=1}^\infty$ eventually has values between $s$ and $s+x$.  But then all these sequence values are upper bounds of $A$, so $s+x$ was not $\sup A$, showing a contradiction.

Suppose $s > \sup A$.  Produce a similar contradiction.

It can be helpful to draw a schematic of what is going on.  In this problem, I would probably represent magnitudes vertically and sequence indices horizontally.  The sketch for the second supposition would be a vertical reflection of that for the first supposition.